# Weird behavior of println() method in Java

Tags: java

```
class W {
    static int count=0;

    W() {
        count++;
        System.out.print("c ");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new W().count+" "+new W().count);
    }
}
```

Expected output

> c 1 c 2

Actual output

> c c 1 2

Why?

Comment: Both Ws have to be created *before* println is called...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The actual order of things executed by the JVM is as follows:

1. 1st `W` object is instantiated and its `count` property read.

   Here the first `c` is send to output.
2. 2nd `W` object is instantiated and its `count` property read.

   Here the second `c` is send to output.
3. The string argument for `System.out.println()` is built. ( == `"1 2"`)
4. The string argument is sent to the output.

Thus the output results to `c c 1 2`.

Comment: so the string is evaluated as "1 2 ", while doing so constructor calls print method, hence first "c c " is printed.....thnx a lot!!!! :)

Comment: it all about precedence of new operator over the concatenate operator. isn't it @ sirko

Comment: @krishnaChandra Yes. You can't read the property of an object, before it's created. Similarly you need all components of the parameter, before the respective method (`println()`) can be called.

Comment: @sirko: but here int count is a static variable I think here the count should not be in the mercy of object because it a static variable...itsn't it. there is no point to access static variable with the object reference.how would you justified your answer

Comment: @krishnaChandra It is a static variable, but is used in a non-static way. If OP had used `W.count` without the `new` keyword, the constructor would not have been called and the output would differ. The question is, e.g., discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4510739/1169798

Comment: @sirko: GOT IT : justified.

Answer (score 7):

In this line:

```
System.out.println(new W().count+" "+new W().count);
```

The instances of `W` are instantiated prior to the evaluation of the rest of the statement.

The order of operations is:

1. Instantiate first new W(), causing c to be printed
2. Evaluate first new W().count
3. Instantiate second new W(), causing c to be printed
4. Evaluate second new W().count
5. Concatenate the result and print.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `System.out.println` statement in the constructor is executed first and then only the calling `System.out.println` executed. Remember the `System.out.pritnln` in constructor executed completely before the calling `System.out.println`
The order is

- new W() causes `System.out.println()` to be called hence printing "C"
- again new W() causes `System.out.println()` to be called hence printing "C"
- After this is complete, outer `System.out.println` prints new count.

Answer (score 0):

the println method in the main needs to know what is its's parameters, so the JVM first  constructs the objects and then send them to the println method

Answer (score 0):

```
class W {
static int count=0;

W() {
    count++;
    System.out.print("c ");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(new W().count+" "+new W().count);
}
```

Because **new W()** will call the constructor W() then it will print "C" out, after that the count become 1 then you call **new W()** again, so another "C" is here. Finally, you call system.out.println(1 + " " + 2). then the 1 2 is in the output buffer.

Answer (score 0):

```
class W {
    static int count=0;

    W() {
        count++;
        System.out.print("c ");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //modify System.out.println(new W().count+" "+new W().count);
        System.out.print(new W().count + " ");
        System.out.print(new W().count);
    }
}

OUTPUT

c 1 c 2
```

The actual order of things executed by the JVM is as follows:

1st W object is instantiated and its count property read.

Here the first c is send to output.

2nd W object is instantiated and its count property read.

Here the second c is send to output.

The string argument for System.out.println() is built. ("1 2")

The string argument is sent to the output.

Thus the output results to c c 1 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
class W {
    static int count=0;

    W() {
        count++;
        System.out.print("c ");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new W().count+" "+new W().count);
    }
}
```

this is to do with the **operator priority** in java.

The **new** operator has higher precedence over the concatenation that's why the second new operator gets priority over the concatenation operator and the second c is getting print.
 after the second call to new W()  the  Statement will look like.

```
 System.out.println(1 +""+2);
```

**and the output will be :- c c 1 2**